Чтение СМС с помощью фреймворка Kivy для Python
Есть ли в фреймворке kivy возможность читать смс на Android?
Может у кого есть конкретные примеры?
Буду очень благодарен.
В инете очень мало информации по такой, казалось бы, простой возможности.
Заранее спасибо!
